# Adding list of customcontrols

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the basic class that I am trying to display:

```
public class Day
{
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }

    public SpecialDay SpecialDay { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeIn { get; private set; }

    public DateTime TimeOut { get; private set; }

    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek

    public TimeSpan TotalHours
}
```

It is contained inside a list in in following class:

```
public class Month
{
    private int _month { get; set; }
    private int _year { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date


    public List<Day> Days { get; private set; }

    public TimeSpan TotalHoursInMonth
}
```

This is the load function of the main display form

```
private void MonthDataForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int bottomOfPreviousDay = -1;

        foreach (var item in MonthDisplaying.Days)
        {
            DayView dayDisplay = new DayView(item);

            if (bottomOfPreviousDay == -1)
            {
                dayDisplay.Top = this.Top + 10;
            }
            else
            {
                dayDisplay.Top = bottomOfPreviousDay + 2;
            }

            bottomOfPreviousDay = dayDisplay.Bottom;
            this.Controls.Add(dayDisplay);
        }

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

The form shows a list of days for a given month like so
[image: display screenshot]

Each line is a separate instance of the `Day` class, and in the next stage of development there will be buttons to perform different actions on each instance.

Is there a better way for calculating the position of the user controls that are being added?  I don't like the way the `if`/`else` looks but I am not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Can you add some more context? What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Are you stacking each of the days on top of eachother? Maybe a screenshot would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to specifically ask for: **Is there a better way for calculating the position of the user controls that are being added? I don't like the way the if/else looks but I am not sure how else to do it.**

My answer will address only this. You can make a better use of the variable and instead of `-1` use `Top + 10` and later `= Bottom + 2`. The code:

```
    int nextTop = this.Top + 10;

    foreach (var item in MonthDisplaying.Days)
    {
        DayView dayDisplay = new DayView(item);

        dayDisplay.Top = nextTop;

        nextTop = dayDisplay.Bottom + 2;

        this.Controls.Add(dayDisplay);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly the kind of solution that I was looking for.